# How to properly init passed property in subclass of UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subclass, init

I have a subclass of UIView that I would like to pass a property to. As much as I've tried, I don't truly understand all elements of initializing.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
class inputWithIncrementView : UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var inputName : String // This is the property I want to receive and init

override init (frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
    // [this is where i will use the inputName property passed on initialization] 
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
}
// [other functions and stuff working fine here]
}
```

I have tried a number of things, but I'm getting confused between the UIView initializer and the way I normally initialize a non-subclassed class.

How do I modify this code to receive the string property, initialize it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize a `UIView` with a custom property you must reconfigure its initializer:

```
class InputWithIncrementView: UIView {
    let inputName: String

    init(inputName: String) {
        self.inputName = inputName
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked. So I don't need this: override init (frame : CGRect) ?

Comment: Not here because you're not overriding the view's standard `init`, you're creating your own initializer, passing through your custom parameters, and then calling `super.init`. `super.init` is the same method as `override init(frame:)` but instead of overriding it you're just calling it later.