# Swift UIView subclass init failing

Tags: swift, uiview

I created a UIView subclass:

```
class RA_Circle: UIView {

        let elipseWidth:CGFloat
        let elipseHeight:CGFloat

        init(elipseWidth: CGFloat, elipseHeight:CGFloat) {

            self.elipseWidth = elipseWidth
            self.elipseHeight = elipseHeight

            super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

    }
```

But the compiler is giving me this error on the required init:

Property 'self.elipseWidth' not initialized at super.init call

I was following this SO Q&A:

[How to properly init passed property in subclass of UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082128/how-to-properly-init-passed-property-in-subclass-of-uiview)

Comment: The error is clear. You need to initialize your two properties before calling `super.init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class definition you're declaring your variable without any default values, and the required initializer is not providing any values before calling super init.

There are a number of ways to deal with this, here's a few...

One way is to provide default values in the property declarations:

```
var elipseWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
var elipseHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
```

The second is to make your properties optional:

```
var elipseWidth: CGFloat?
var elipseHeight: CGFloat?
```

A third is to provide default values in the required initializer:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    elipseWidth = 14.0
    elipseHeight = 14.0
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `let` variable declarations to `var` and optional. In this case, you would initialize them in `awakeFromNib()` or at some later time.

Comment: This is only one possible solution. There are several other solutions.